# Listener for a specific sound from sound stream using Python

Tags: python, audio, stream, listener

I play a video game. The game plays many sounds simultaneously. Is there any solution to create a listener for the specific sound from the game's audio stream using Python?

Comment: It's easier finding the sound file in the game data and checking the games memory for it than trying to isolate the sound in a stream.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I figured out that the game has been written using Unity3d. The sound data has *.wem and *.bnk files. I'm the noob in this direction a programming and I don't know how to hook the game memory to listen playing sound.